# How to prevent establishment of SSL connection on each request

Tags: https, jersey, jersey-client

I use jersey 1.7. My client communicates with server over HTTPS. I figured out that HTTPS connection is established for each different request (URL). I would like to keep the same connection for multiple requests during specific period of time. I configure the client as it is describe in https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with and send request via WebResource.Builder

```
public Response post(String actionName, Request request) {
    WebResource webResource = rwsClient.resource( serverURL + actionName);
    WebResource.Builder requestBuilder = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
    Response response = requestBuilder.post(Request.class, request);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Connections from HTTP 1.1 requests are considered persistent unless declared otherwise.
If your client is making HTTP 1.0 request, they can pass the header "Connection: Keep-Alive"

Then you have to look at the connection timeout settings of your web servers. For Apache 2.2 for example, it is very low at only 5 seconds by default. Check your web server documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. HTTP connection is persistent. When I turned on HTTPS I see that connection is established for each request. Web server configuration is the following: Timeout 300, KeepAlive On, MaxKeepAliveRequests 2000, KeepAliveTimeout 60. Is something missing for persistent SSL connection?

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot, so you'll need a sysadmin to look at the packets/handshakes/etc. Any hop in between your client and server (like a load-balancer) could be configured to drop connections quickly...